# Memory Leakage with ThreadPoolExecutor python

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-management, memory-leaks, threadpoolexecutor

I have a process that fetches some ids and based on those ids, i fetch (pandas)dataframes from the database, after some processing, the data frames are stored to file system using to_csv and then the data frames are deleted using `del`.

the fetch of dataframe and processing is done using ThreadPoolExecutor.

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_workers) as executor:
  return list(executor.map(func, args))
```

where `func` is the process and `args` are the customer ids.

despite the del and the thread expected to be ended, i see that memory usage is still there, and my hunch is that the data frames still persist in memory.

how can i clean out the memory..??

PS: I also did try gc...not useful

Answer (score -1):

Before you can clean out the memory, you must understand what is accumulating.

Run the sequence a few dozen times and gather a live core (for example, using gcore), or make sure your "ulimit -c" value is such that you can create a core when the process dies and just run the sequence in a loop until it dies.

When you have a suitable core, open it with **chap** see (https://github.com/vmware/chap) and start with the following commands:

```
redirect on
summarize leaked
summarize used /sortby bytes
```

If there is actually a leak, in terms of allocations no longer being reachable, the results of **summarize leaked** will tell you that.  If there is no leak, the output of **summarize used /sortby bytes** should give you a good idea of where to look next.

There are likely to be some huge buffers associated with pandas.  You can find them by

```
summarize used /minsize 100000
```

Then follow incoming edges from there.  If you get stuck, post your partial results from the summaries and I can probably get you unstuck.

Comment: Ok...that's a good suggestion... unfortunately I don't have the luxury of applying custom vms and all...if something like memory profiler can be done, then I may be able to try that...

Comment: Why would you need a custom VM?  Is the issue that you are not running on Linux?

Comment: I mean I am limited by commands executing the python runtime...

Comment: I am not yet clear why that prevents you from at least gathering a live core.  If you are on Linux, and you know the pid of your process:   gcore <pid>

Comment: its a custom environment that is use and we do not have like live access to the run time os and all...we simply pass the binaries to the environment...

is there anything that we can do from inside the python script..??

Comment: I guess you could investigate your specific theory about data frames staying in memory by using sys.getrefcount() on such an object just before the last reference known to you goes out of scope.  A value > 2 would confirm your theory.

Comment: got 1 df value at 3 rest 4 df refcount = 2

Comment: The df with a refcount of 3 seems problematic to me.  The ones with the refcount of 2 are likely not because before getrefcount you expect to have at least one (or else how would you be able to make the call) and during getrefcount the count is bumped by 1.

Comment: Is there a way to find where the copy may be..??

Comment: It would be trivial to find it, if you could run chap, enough so that making a minimally reproducible example run on Linux would be worthwhile.   Based on how references are represented in python, I don't know of any way to do what you want other than to figure out back-edges for the graph.   Maybe the owners of your environment are familiar with other debugging tools that are available there but I can't help you further at this point unless you can reproduce it on Linux.